# JQUERY, appending an LI to a UL, and then animating that LI

Tags: jquery

I have an UL:

```
<ul id="news-feed">.....</ul>
```

I'd like to be able to append a LI to the top of the list and have that appended item slideDown into place.

```
$("#news-feed").append('<li">This is my item</li>').hide().slideDown();
```

Problem I'm having is the above code is sliding the news-feed item down, and not the appended item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you were hoping to chain it all together, you can use `appendTo()` instead. It will return the new `<li>` element so you can slide it down.

```
$('<li>This is my item</li>').appendTo("#news-feed").hide().slideDown();
```

**EDIT:** As @cletus noted, you should use `.prependTo()` as he did in his answer instead of `.appendTo()`. This will bring the new item to the top of the list.

Comment: +1 You both got this posted before I finished typing my answer. I probably recommend putting the hide sooner like you said in your other comment.

Comment: @Doug - I think you're right about `.hide()`. And I didn't do the `.prependTo()` either. I thought about it, then forgot about it!

Comment: It's to the top of the list so this should be `prependTo()` not `appendTo()`.

Comment: @cletus - Yeah, I know. I thought of it, but then ended up merely rearranging the OP's code, and forgot. You've got it covered in yours. I'll make note of it, though.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to chain it together nicely, flip it around and use [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) instead of [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/). Either:

```
$("<li>").text("This is my item").hide().prependTo("#news-feed").slideDown();
```

or

```
$("<li>This is my item</li>").hide().prependTo("#news-feed").slideDown();
```

I prefer the first because it handles escaping. The second doesn't. But it's largely a matter of preference.

Comment: +1 - You were quicker, and probably put `.hide()` in a better position. (Not sure if it makes a difference or not.)

Comment: +1 for suggesting `prependTo`. If using 1.4+, then `$("<li>", { text: "This is my item" })...` is probably the best combo of both your methods.

Comment: Why do the hide when you can do style="display:none" inline? Is that faster?

Comment: @Kerry my philosophy is that if there's an API call for something, use it. Second-guessing libraries, frameworks and compiler's is an irrelevant distraction.

Comment: Bost methods use an API, some are much more efficient than others

Answer (score 3):

Usually we take it this way:

```
var newsItem = $("<ul></ul>"); // Create a template item and clone from it

var parentItem = $( /* whatever selector string */ );

//  …

newsItem.clone().text("blah").hide().appendTo(parentItem).toggle('slide');
```

Also, when you say “add to the top of the list”, usually `prepend()` works better as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first you need to make it display none, then make it slide down:

```
$("#news-feed").append('<li style="display:none">This is my item</li>').find('li:last').slideDown();
```

If that doesn't work, break it into two statements:

```
$('#news-feed').append('<li style="display:none">This is my item</li>');
$('#news-feed li:last').slideDown();
```

Comment: So replace append with prepend and your golden

Comment: The animation isn't smooth and doesn't even slide down? it just bounces

Comment: If you did prepend, you also have to change the `li:last` to `li:first`. I would have to see your page, but I use this method all the time and I have no problems.

Comment: min-height was messing it up. changing it to just height made it work!